# How to setup Google Apps for Business email on iOS

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, ios

I use Google Apps for Business to manage email for one of my domains, and I have all emails to `xyz@domain` forwarded to `admin@domain` and I would like to receive set this account up on my iOS device.  Does anyone know how to do this? or where there are instructions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The easiest method would be to install the [Gmail app for iOS](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gmail/id422689480?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo=2).**

Otherwise you can add your Google Apps account using **IMAP** to the built in mail app using the method below (taken from [this Google help article](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=77702)):

> To configure the 'Mail' app on an Apple device for access to Gmail,
>   just follow these steps:
>
> Make sure you've enabled IMAP in your main Gmail settings (usually on
>   by detault for Google apps addresses)
>
> 1. Open the Settings app on your device
> 2. Tap Mail, Contacts, Calendars
> 3. Tap Add Account...
> 4. Tap Gmail
> 5. Enter your account information, being sure to use your full Gmail address, including '@gmail.com' **(or in this case '@domain')**
> 6. Tap Next
> 7. Tap Save

Also, Google Apps has another method called **[Google Sync](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/topic.py?topic=14252)** which uses Microsoft Exchange. This method allows you to enforce device policies. Instructions on setting up Google Sync on an iOS device can be found [here](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138740&topic=21161&ctx=topic). There is also a comparison of using [Google Sync vs. IMAP vs. Mobile Browser](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=161769&topic=24940&ctx=topic)

Comment: The instructions you provided in the block will work, but there is a little gotcha: If you send e-mail with that configured account via your device, it will be sent to the receiver's spam inbox. Looks like the solution to this is to use SMTP in port 587